# WebStorm doesn't hit breakpoints in Angular CLI app

Tags: angular, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2019.1.1 Build #WS-191.6707.60, built on April 16, 2019. I am attempting to debug an Angular application that is based on Angular 5.2. I followed the instructions on [JetBrains support website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/angular.html#angular_running_and_debugging) as well as numerous YouTube videos but it looks like the debugger never runs or hits my breakpoint.

I setup my run/debug configuration as shown in the screen capture below. I am using the default Angular CLI configuration pointing to `localhost:4200`. The instructions at JetBrains support website say to launch the app via the green triangular "play" button and then once the app is running then click the "bug" icon next to the play button. This pops up a dialog warning that the project is not allowed to run in parallel (of which I cancel out). I have also tried just clicking the "bug" icon, and though the project compiles via webpack and runs it never stops at the breakpoints I set in WebStorm.

[image: Run/Debug configuration]

[image: Parallel Warning]

Debugging within Chrome using the dev tools works just fine and the breakpoints I set there work fine, however I really would like to be able to do the debugging inside of WebStorm.

The instruction also mention that WebStorm creates a default **Angular Application** configuration but I don't see one being created.

[image: WebStorm documentation]

I had this process working before when using the evaluation of WebStorm but after I bought a license and reinstalled WebStorm it no longer works. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have **Angular Application** run configuration above **npm** group in **JavaScript Debug** but in your case it's collapsed.

If you don't have it there it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure the way I had it running previously was using node.js configuration. I would cick play and webpack would compile in the console. I would then have to manually launch my browser to localhost:4200 manually, but then it would hit breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

The `Angular Application` configuration that is created by default. Is just the "JavaScript Debug" profile with a custom name.

Click the "+" icon to add a configuration and select "JavaScript Debug".

The configuration you have in your example is for debugging JavaScript on the command line via NodeJS. It's for debugging a npm script.

You will also need to install the JetBrains browser extension. Here is the link for the Chrome browser (I'm not sure about other browsers).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji

Without the extension the IDE will not remotely debug what's happening in the browser.

Comment: I had thought that WebStorm no longer required the Chrome extension. Is this not the case?

Comment: @webworm you don't need the extension if you launch Chrome directly from the IDE. You need it if you want to attach the debugger to a running instance of Chrome. Honestly I never do the later.

Comment: I installed the chrome extension and when I select "Inspect in Webstorm" I get the notification that `JetBrains IDE support is debugging this browser`. However, I cannot hit any breakpoints.